# Upgrading DHTMLX to a new version

Tags: dhtmlx

I was wondering, how often does DHTMLX offer a new version and how hard do you find it to upgrade your applications to the new version. This is namely a critical part in my research, but I cant seem to find any problems with updates. This question is just to make sure that my findings are correct.

Please suffice with: version number, DHTMLX component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work for DHTMLX. During the past 3 years we released one major update per year. Currently we're preparing the next version which we hope will be available in beta till the end of April 2012. We try to make the new releases backwards compatible and provide the upgrade path to the latest release (like [here](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=migrating_to_version_3.0)).

Comment: As for DHTMLX Touch, the next update is planned on May. The new version 1.1 will be backward compatible as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've used many controls from the dhtmlxsuite in our app for the past 5 yrs. They are pretty good at making things backwards compatible, but not always. When going from v3 to v4 just a few months ago, there was quite a lot I had to do get my code back up and running.  Also there dropped a few features that were supported in v3, this is not so good in my opinion. But overall, I really like the dhtmlx controls, they are an integral part of our product which now is used all over the world by thousands of users (http://www.ecosys.net/ecosys-epc/).